# Can an individual who has had a covid-19 vaccination test positive and is that a problem?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, coronavirus, test, test-results

Can an individual who has had a covid-19 vaccination test positive and is that a problem?

Up to now and for some time to come, testing has been important to help control the spread of this disease.

Vaccines are now a real prospect so when that starts, would testing strategies and interpretation of data need to change, to accomodate for a growing number of individuals who've had the vaccine.